# Sewing up the tallit, so that it always stays perfectly on your shoulders? Adding snaps?

Tags: clothing, tzitzis, tallit-gadol, holy-objects

The tallit forever falls off your shoulders because of gravity and has to be raised again and again.  Why is it not sewn together so it always stays perfectly on your shoulders?  (Sure, if you do, wrapping it over your head becomes less majestic, but it can still be done.)  At least, why aren't snaps provided so you can fix its position in different ways for different prayers?

Comment: "Sewn together" - sewn onto your shoulders/sleeves?

Comment: However you want it to stay on your shoulders, sew it up together that way. (Not on your clothes!)

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining what you mean by "sew it up together". Together with what exactly?

Comment: Sew it up itself instead of it being a big rectangle.  I don't know how else to say it.

Comment: If it's not a big rectangle, would it even need Tzitzit? What would be the point of wearing it

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Maybe others can help describe -at least to me- what "sewing up (together)" would look like while, obviously, still remaining a kosher talit.

Comment: Picture yourself wearing the tallit.  It falls off your shoulders.  Then you raise it back up.  With sewing in the right place, it will never fall off.

Comment: Note that some companies advertise "non-slip" talleisim. Not entirely sure what those are (some sort of different type of weave), but that might be a more practical suggestion than trying to redesign the tallis.

Comment: @ Double AA  You can pick up the tzitzit whether it's sewn or not.

Comment: I think that if this were sewn to your clothes (with a needle & thread) scuh that your shirt and tallit seemd like one piece, it would probably nullify the concept of wearing tzitzit / tallit as being a separate garment. Tallit clips look beautiful and they prevent the tallit from slipping off your shoulders. I haven't seen anyone invent velcro strips on the tallit as well as on your shoulders, but, hey, you can invent this idea and market it! Snaps are a bit trickier as they are not easily removable.

Comment: @mau what does picking up Tzitzit have to do with anything

Comment: "Snaps are a bit trickier as they are not easily removable".  Why would you want to remove them?

Comment: @Salmononius2, "non-slip" refers to the weave. Most talliyot now come with non-slip options and some are only available that way (eg. Belz and Turkish or boxknit talliyot)

Comment: Is it possible that your technique is wrong? Mine always used to fall off, then I got advice to curl it under itself on each shoulder (I would curl it up, over itself previously)

Comment: I've seen people wear a clip on below the atara on their tallis to keep it on the shoulders better. Something like [this](https://www.nadavart.com/product-category/judaica/tallit-clips/).